# case statement multiple conditions - date and status

Tags: sql, date, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have one date field in my service order data that can have multiple statuses (queue, complete, canceled) and am trying to make my case statement fit the conditions correctly in the instance where the queue date is after complete date (the SO was re-opened after being completed once).

I have this written, but it is giving me two rows of data-  one with the correct complete date for a specific SO, NULL in this case, and one with the original complete date.

my data looks like this before case statements, etc.:

| SO# | Date | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2/1/23 | Queue |
| 12345 | 1/28/23 | Comp |
| 12345 | 1/27/23 | Queue |

this SO was completed then opened back up and i'd like to read it as:

| SO # | Queue Date | Comp Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2/1/23 | NULL |

```
SELECT
M.BI_SO_NBR,
SQ.start_queue_date,
SQ.CANCL_DATE,
case when (ta.bi_work_event_cd ='COMP' and comp_date < start_queue_date) then null else SQ.COMP_DATE  end as comp_date2
FROM
BI_SO_MASTER M
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_SO_DET D ON M.BI_SO_NBR = D.BI_SO_NBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_WRKFLW_TASKS T ON D.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = T.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_TASK_ASG_SCHED A ON T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = A.BI_WRKFLW_TASK_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_TASK_ACT TA oN T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = TA.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     (SELECT  
          TA.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY, 
          max(CASE WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd ='START') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
            ELSE (CASE WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd = 'QUEUE') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm 
            else NULL END) END) AS start_queue_date ,
          max(CASE WHEN(  ta.bi_work_event_cd ='COMP') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
          else NULL ENd) AS COMP_DATE,
          max(CASE WHEN(ta.bi_work_event_cd ='CANCL') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
          else NULL END) AS CANCL_DATE
      FROM bi_task_act ta 
      GROUP BY ta.bi_wrkflw_tasks_key ) SQ 
   ON (T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = SQ.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY)
```

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without seeing your sample data and expected output, but I expect that your query returns two rows regardless of the case statement. Remember that the case statement will be applied to each row in your result set. If you're wanting to just return the one row then consider moving your logic from the case statement to the where clause. IE: WHERE ta.bi_work_event_cd ='COMP' and comp_date < start_queue_date. This would filter the result down to the one row.

Comment: @TylerEZPZGG thank you, apologies my data set looks like this:

SO# | Date | Code
12345 | 2/1/23 | Queue
12345 | 1/28/23 | Comp
12345 | 1/27/23 | Queue

this SO was completed then opened back up and i'd like to read it as:

SO # | Queue Date | Comp Date
12345 | 2/1/23 | NULL

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your data in that. Comments are not good for much besides commenting. `max(CASE WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd ='START') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm ELSE (CASE WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd = 'QUEUE') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm else NULL END) END) AS start_queue_date` is the same a `MAX(CASE WHEN bi_work_event_cd IN ('START','QUEUE') THEN bi_Event_dt_tm END) as start_queue_dt`, but that doesn't answer your question. Do you have more than on `BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY` for each `BI_SO_NBR`? Is `BI_SO_NBR` unique in `BI_SO_DET`?

Comment: yes, there can be many task keys for an SO, but they are unique to the task, bi so nbr is unique as well

Comment: Why don't you use actual field names in the sample tables? I don't quite understand the rule for your record selection. Do you just want the most recent record for each SO?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where you can move the CASE statement to the sub-query and then join it onto your existing result set. You can use similar logic to replace your `SQ` subquery. If you're still getting an extra row, my guess is that it is from joining the `BI_TASK_ACT` table to the `SQ` subquery.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `bi_task_act` (
    `so_number` VARCHAR(20),
    `so_date` DATE,
    `so_code` VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO bi_task_act
  (`so_number`, `so_date`, `so_code`)
VALUES
  ('12345', '2023-02-01',   'Queue'),
  ('12345', '2023-01-28',   'Comp'),
  ('12345', '2023-01-27',   'Queue'),
  ('67890', '2023-11-01',   'Queue'),
  ('67890', '2023-12-28',   'Comp');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.so_number,
       a.queue_date,
       a.comp_date,
       CASE
           WHEN a.comp_date < a.queue_date THEN NULL
           ELSE a.comp_date
       END AS comp_date2
FROM
  (SELECT a.so_number,
          MAX(CASE
                  WHEN a.so_code = 'Queue' THEN a.so_date
              END) AS queue_date,
          MAX(CASE
                  WHEN a.so_code = 'Comp' THEN a.so_date
              END) AS comp_date
   FROM bi_task_act a
   GROUP BY a.so_number) a;
```

| so_number | queue_date | comp_date | comp_date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2023-02-01 | 2023-01-28 |  |
| 67890 | 2023-11-01 | 2023-12-28 | 2023-12-28 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

**Here's an example of how you can incorporate it into your query:**

```
SELECT M.BI_SO_NBR,
       SQ.start_queue_date,
       SQ.CANCL_DATE,
       SQ.comp_date2
FROM BI_SO_MASTER M
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_SO_DET D ON M.BI_SO_NBR = D.BI_SO_NBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_WRKFLW_TASKS T ON D.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = T.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN BI_TASK_ASG_SCHED A ON T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = A.BI_WRKFLW_TASK_KEY
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT a.*,
          CASE
              WHEN a.COMP_DATE < a.start_queue_date THEN NULL
              ELSE a.COMP_DATE
          END AS comp_date2
   FROM
     (SELECT TA.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY,
             max(CASE
                     WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd ='START') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
                     ELSE (CASE
                               WHEN (ta.bi_work_event_cd = 'QUEUE') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
                               ELSE NULL
                           END)
                 END) AS start_queue_date,
             max(CASE WHEN(ta.bi_work_event_cd ='COMP') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) AS COMP_DATE,
             max(CASE WHEN(ta.bi_work_event_cd ='CANCL') THEN ta.bi_event_dt_tm
                     ELSE NULL
                 END) AS CANCL_DATE
      FROM bi_task_act ta
      GROUP BY ta.bi_wrkflw_tasks_key) a) SQ ON (T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = SQ.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY);
```